# Converting D strings to char* with templates

Tags: arrays, d, c-strings

Learning D and throughly enjoying the process but this bit of code to convert a D string to `char*` is puzzling me. I stumbled on it by just blindly intuiting how templates work but I'd like to know how it actually works

```
import core.stdc.stdio;
import core.stdc.string;
import core.stdc.stdlib;

extern (C):

/// Convert a string to a char array
template charify(const string str, const size_t length) {
    void charify(char* arr) {
        foreach(i; 0 .. str.length) {
            if (i >= length) {
                break;
            }
            arr[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto k = cast(char*)malloc(4 * char.sizeof);
    charify!("abcdef", 3)(k);
    printf("%s %d\n", k, strlen(k));
    return 0;
}
```

The output as I expect is `abc 3` but I don't really know why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: In case you are not aware, Phobos has a function to do this called toStringz (and to go the other way fromStringz). It does use the GC, but this is the way I would do it as well. No need for templates.

https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/master/std/string.d#L243

Comment: You should also be able to do an array copy in there instead of the loop: `arr[0 .. len] = str[0 .. len];` then `arr[len] = 0;` to terminate it. Though note that string literals just work as C strings as well, so no need to do anything special with them.

Answer (score 2):

The D standard library already has everything you need - the [toStringz](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.toStringz) and [fromStringz](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.fromStringz) functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's confusing here, but I'll give it a go. If I haven't covered something, feel free to ask. :)

First, there's a bug - your resulting string is not always null-terminated. `malloc` gives random data, not initialized to 0. Your function should set the last char to `'\0'` to fix this.

The `extern(C)` line is unnecessary - you're not going to call `charify` from C, especially since it's a templated function.

In Phobos, the D standard library, there's the function [toStringz](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.toStringz) which does what your function should do, but uses the GC.

Anyways, as to what your function is actually doing:

The `template charify(...) { void charify(...){...} }` pattern is known as an [eponymous template](https://dlang.org/spec/template.html#implicit_template_properties). An equivalent and shorter signature would be `void charify(const string str, const size_t length)(char* arr)`.

Since `length` is a value type (no pointers involved), and strings in D are immutable, `const` is unnecessary on both template parameters.

Other improvements that could be done is using array operations instead of foreach, turning the entire body of the function into `arr[0..min(str.length, length)] = str[];`, and of course null termination.

The cleaned-up version would be:

```
void charify(string str, size_t length)(char* arr) {
    arr[0..min(str.length, length)] = str[];
    arr[length-1] = '\0';
}
```

In your case a template is not really warranted - a function taking str and length as regular parameters would be equivalent in basically every way:

```
void charify(string str, size_t length, char* arr) {
    arr[0..min(str.length, length)] = str[];
    arr[length-1] = '\0';
}
```

The only difference is there's now only one list of parameters, and it's invoked `charify("abcdef", 3, k)`.

Also, string literals in D are always null-terminated, so can be safely passed to C functions by means of their [`.ptr` property](https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#array-properties). Note that this is only the case when you have code that looks like `printf("%s", "foo".ptr)`, not `printf("%s", functionThatReturnsString().ptr)` or even `printf("%s", "foo"[0..1].ptr)`. In the `"foo"[0..1]` case "foo" will be printed, because no null terminator is inserted after the slice taken. In the `functionThatReturnsString` case, the returned string may or may not be null-terminated, and if not, a large part of your memory may be printed before a `'\0'` is finally encountered.

Comment: I'm using `-betterC` flag to avoid the runtime so can't use GC.